# Using Asynchronous Controller to Fill DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, asynchronous

I have a Site which creates some form of a Report. The whole process takes up to a Minute. To increase the performance I was thinking about turning the **synchronous** controller into a **Asynchronous** Controller.

I read through a lot of topics, and guides but I just don't seem to get the hang of it.

Right now I have a DataSet which has ~15 DataTables. Each of the ~15 DataTables is filled by a different Query.

To convert this Page to a Asynchronous Controller i created a **ConnectionManager**, created 15 **getMethods** for each DataTable and each DataTable is in the Model. I also created **2 Controller** - one called **[Name]Async** and one called **[Name]Complete**. However, now I am stuck.

How do I create ~15 Threads and assign each the Task to populate a DataTable with the getMethod?!

Here some parts of the Code.

**Controller**

```
public class RunTableStatisticsController : AsyncController
{
    public void RunTableStatisticsAsync()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment(2);

        // Create Threads who populate RunTableStatisticsModels DataTables
    }

    public ViewResult RunTableStatisticsComplete(RunTableStatisticsModel voModel)
    {
        return View(voModel);
    }
}
```

**getMethod**

```
public static DataTable getDataTable1()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dtTemp= new DataTable();
                dtTemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName1", typeof(string)));
dtTemp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName2", typeof(string)));

                string sQuery = "select * from 1";

                // Instantiate the Command Object
                OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(sQuery, ..MyConnectionManager.Connection);
                dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                // Execute the Stored Procedure
                OleDbDataReader dr = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DataRow row = dtTemp.NewRow();
                    row["ColumnName1"] = dr["ColumnName1"]);
                    row["ColumnName2"] = dr["ColumnName2"];

                    dtTemp.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                return dtTemp;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: Reading database.", ex);
            }
        }
```

Correspondend I do have in my Model

```
public DataTable dtTable1{ get; set; }
```

And then I have a View which has Telerik Grid Extensions which will be filled by the Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the TPL to parallelize the retrieval of those DataTables. Here's an example with 2, if you have more, you might consider using collections of DataTables:

```
public class RunTableStatisticsController : AsyncController 
{
    public void RunTableStatisticsAsync()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment(2);

        // Create tasks that populate RunTableStatisticsModels DataTables

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["dt1"] = DAL.GetDataTable1();
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            AsyncManager.Parameters["dt2"] = DAL.GetDataTable2();
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        });
    }

    public ViewResult RunTableStatisticsComplete(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
    {
        var model = new RunTableStatisticsModel
        {
            DtTable1 = dt1,
            DtTable2 = dt2,
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. From here I can finish the rest. Thanks a lot.